# using one for loop to loop through multiple directories

Tags: bash

I want to have a for loop to check the files in my current directory and 2 specific "sub-sub-directories" called folder1 and folder2. Instead of going:

```
for file in * 
do stuff

done

for file in "./sub_dir/folder1"/*
do stuff

done

for file in "./sub_dir/folder2"/*
do stuff

done
```

is there a way to do all this with one for loop? Something along the lines of

```
for file in * || "./sub_dir/folder1"/* || "./sub_dir/folder2"/*
do stuff

done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You could just remove the `||` in your second code snippet. For instance: `for file in * "./sub_dir/folder1"/* "./sub_dir/folder2"/*; do echo $file; done`. You'll have to check that each `$file` is not a folder (if that's important to you), since it'll list those too. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes it is, thanks!!

Comment: This might not answer your questions specifically, but you should probably use find instead of a for loop

Comment: `for` loops have lilmits to the size, both number of "words" and overall character counts. Better to use `find ....` followed by `| xargs your_cmd  [opts]...` Search here for `[bash] find xargs` and there will be 100's of examples (good and bad, so read carefully, try something and then post a new Q here). Good luck